# Explanation of two arguments for jQuery .each() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following jQuery, the `.each()` method takes two arguments: `'ul li a'` and `menu`. What do these two arguments mean?

```
var menu = $('.menu');
$('ul li a', menu).each(function() {
    $(this).append('<span />');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Appear Offline</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second parameter to the jQuery function is the context.  This tells jQuery to *only* search for elements that are in that context

So for your example:

```
$('ul li a', menu).each(function() {
    $(this).append('<span />');
});
```

This will only search for anchors within li's within a `ul`, **that are also located inside of menu**.

This can be a very useful optimization since it can significantly cut down the amount of space jQuery has to search.

**EDIT**

To possibly make this a bit clearer (as jfriend00 points out), your particular example, `$('ul li a', menu)`, is equivalent to `$('.menu ul li a')`

The context parameter is explained here in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: To clarify: `$('ul li a', menu)` is the same as `$('.menu ul li a')` in this particular case.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I added that to my answer - thank you, and enjoy your new badges :)

Answer (score 1):

Hello Brother Assalamu Alaikkum,
The explanation is as follows,
The first parameter is **'ul li a'** It means that it searches for the **anchor tag** within the **list item tag** which in turn present inside the **unordered list tag**. This first argument is the sub context.

The second parameter **menu** which is the main context. That is jquery searches for the elements with the **class name** as **"menu"**.

Finally jquery searches the sub context within the main context. So the jquery searches for the main context **"menu"** first and then it searches the sub context within the main context. The keyword **"each"** denotes all the sub elements to be searched within the main element.

hope this helps you.